# Is it safe to define more than 120 signs?

Tags: vimscript, help-system, signs

I am working on a plugin that could potentially define more than 120 different `signs`. The vim / neovim documentation specifies that you can define **about 120** signs (not sure why this number and why so ambigous). From `:he sign-define`

```
:sign define {name} {argument}...
        Define a new sign or set attributes for an existing sign.
        The {name} can either be a number (all digits) or a name
        starting with a non-digit.  Leading zeros are ignored, thus
        "0012", "012" and "12" are considered the same name.
        About 120 different signs can be defined.
```

The thing is I have already tried to define well over 500 signs and place them as well and I did not see any issues on my system in both vim and neovim. I was wondering if there are any *dangers* in doing this, or any performance issues.

If anyone is curios how to add so many signs:

```
" permutations of 2 with repetition
function! Permutations(lst, counter, res)
  if a:counter == len(a:lst)
    return a:res
  endif
  let l:res = copy(a:res) + map(copy(a:lst),
        \ { idx, val -> a:lst[a:counter] . val })
  let l:counter = a:counter + 1
  return Permutations(a:lst, l:counter, l:res)
endfunction

" ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', ..., 'zy', 'zz']
function! DefineSigns()
  let l:signs = Permutations(
        \ map(range(97, 97 + 25), 'nr2char(v:val)'), 0, [])
  for i in l:signs
    call sign_define(
          \ 'signs' . i,
          \ {'text': len(i) == 1 ? ' ' . i : i, 'texthl': 'MoreMsg'})
  endfor
endfunction
```

```
:call DefineSigns() | echo len(sign_getdefined())
676
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the documentation is outdated with respect to that limit. I'm looking at the code for `alloc_new_sign()`...

```
    // Check that next_sign_typenr is not already being used.
    // This only happens after wrapping around.  Hopefully
    // another one got deleted and we can use its number.
...
    if (lp->sn_typenr == next_sign_typenr)
    {
        ++next_sign_typenr;
        if (next_sign_typenr == MAX_TYPENR)
...
        if (next_sign_typenr == start)
        {
            vim_free(sp);
            emsg(_("E612: Too many signs defined"));
```

`MAX_TYPENR` is defined as 65535 in my build. Perhaps in the past it was assigned to a smaller type (`unsigned char`? Does C have those? I can't remember.) and thus was limited to a smaller number. Or it was limited due to some condition that no longer applies.

Regardless, looks like you can add as many signs as you need...unless you're doing something absolutely crazy. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I was assuming the documentation is outdated but had no idea how to check.

Comment: @B Layer How did you get the value of this `MAX_TYPENR` ?

Comment: Glad to be of service. Yeah, talk to a dev who knows something about it or dive into code. Those were pretty much the only options.

Comment: When syntax highlighting was disabled at compile time, the block of code in vim.h used to define unsigned char sattr_T and MAX_TYPENR 255, so 120 signs is a rule-of-thumb as this limit is used by other things.  However, with syntax highlighting, the limit was (almost) always 65535.

Comment: @skamsie `ag MAX_TYPENR` in the vim source tree (it's in vim.h). :)

Comment: @Mass What do you mean by syntax highlighting being disabled at compile time? You predef'ed out so it's disabled in the build maybe?

Comment: Yeah, `N  *+syntax*  Syntax highlighting |syntax|`; if you build vim in "tiny" or "small" configurations, the +syntax (highlighting) feature is disabled, so less "attributes" are required.  The reason, of course is memory savings, which today is less important than maintenance concerns, so this distinction (general sign limit) was dropped.

Comment: Cool. I'll add that info to my answer if you don't mind. How do you know, BTW. Do you / have you contributed? Or an avid vim-dev mailing list subscriber? :)

Comment: @Mass You should probably make that an answer and include all those details... Vim tiny might still be relevant, it's the default one installed in some setups (though not sure whether it even supports signs...)

Comment: Mass can do what he wants but calling that an answer sounds like a stretch. It's interesting but supplemental historical info and "if you use tiny version limit is..." and neither directly deal with OPs problem (people who use tiny version probably won't be surprised to hear that given how many other ways that version is limited/restricted).

Comment: (I'd think that even without an answer here. This question is pretty niche and isn't going to generate much activity so I'm not thinking about points getting siphoned away from my answer or other such silliness. LOL. In case someone had that thought. )